# How do I stop matplotlib.pyplot from changing the order of my cmap ListedColormap in Python 3.8.6?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm implementing the A* algorithm for pathfinding on a 2-dimensional grid. The algorithm functions fine, but when using matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(), the colors denoting each square on the grid sometimes change. My code is consistent with this:

```
dataout = [
[1,2,2,2,0],
[2,1,4,3,0],
[2,1,3,2,0],
[0,2,1,1,1],
]

pyplot.figure(figsize=(len(dataout[0]), len(dataout)))
            
colormap = colors.ListedColormap(["lightblue","yellow","blue","black", "lightgreen"])
pyplot.imshow(dataout, cmap=colormap)
pyplot.show()
```

In this example the dataout matrix corresponds to the following legend:

1. Node in the outputted path
2. Neighbor node
3. Obstacle
4. Visited node

The issue arises when all the visited nodes are part of the outputted path (no 4 will be present in dataout[]). This changes the values the colors are assigned to when the image is displayed.

How can I force the colors to be consistent even when some color values may not be present in dataout[]?

Comment: `imshow(...., vmin=0, vmax=4)` would set a fixed correspondence between numbers and colors.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like imshow is using the whole color map over the full range of dataout values, hence different colors depending on presence of 4 or not in dataout.
I worked it around like this (scaling the colors list to the range of dataout values:

```
colormap = colors.ListedColormap(["lightblue","yellow","blue","black", "lightgreen"][0:np.max(dataout)+1])
```